# asp.net datatables sorting formatted-number

Tags: asp.net, datatables

I am working on a project. I am sorting the data with the datatables in the project `2017/1` `2017/2` `2016/1` `2018/90`. When I wrote it as html, I found the solution thanks to allan, but when I do it with repeater, it does not sort it correctly. could help me ? thanks.

Project in here : http://jsfiddle.net/fm8so8na/9/

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You need to sort the source data and then bind it to the Repeater.

Comment: i share codes below